# Transitioning between 90 and 100 ohm diff pairs using coupling caps?

Tags: pcb, usb, differential

I'm building a PCB carrier for an FPGA SoM. The SoM has 100 ohm diff pairs routed for all the high speed IO. I'm implementing USB 3 on the carrier so should be routing 90 ohm diff pairs. What is the best method for guaranteeing signal integrity? Normally coupling caps are only used on TX pair for USB3 but this FPGA required coupling caps on both RX and TX pairs... can I route one side of the caps 90 ohm and the other side 100 ohm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've described will cause an impedance discontinuity and will negatively affect signal integrity, qualitatively speaking. That is, at the point (assuming for this particular instance the connector is neglected) your SoM meets the PCB, there will be a discontinuity from 100R to 90R and you will get some degradation of your signal, which for USB 3.0 would likely manifest as a shrinking of the eye.

It's important to understand where your routing requirements come from. Silicon vendors are not necessarily the system integrators who are not necessarily the PCB designer and they can (and do!) issue conflicting requirements on what to do with your design.

Your FPGA SoM vendor assumedly has in-depth knowledge of the FPGA on their device. They believe that routing 100R was the correct choice for the differential pairs and the transceivers on the device.

In this case, what FPGA are you using? Do they have an application note on applying their transceivers to USB 3.0 usage? What are those pairs being routed too on your host PCB? I would start with what the silicon is expecting or requires, and try to provide it a channel that meets that need. Without knowing more, as you have originally posted with having an FPGA SoM with known impedance, I would match that on your board.

Also, keep in mind the tolerance of your PCB; +/-10% tolerance on a 100ohm line is already a big number that gives some wiggle room as well.

Comment: Thank you. It is a Xilinx Zynq SoC and yeah there is plenty of Xilinx info on how to implement USB3, but this particular SoM is generalized and not made for USB 3 specifically thus high speed diff pairs are all 100 ohm. My pcb continues the connectorized IO and takes it to the final USB implementation.

I was spit balling a bit since there are coupling caps for both TX and RX pairs so thought that there might be an opportunity there. Not sure how impedance discontinuities operate through series caps.

Otherwise I agree, just run 100 ohm since that is what is done on the SoM.

Comment: Suspected it might have been an UltraScale+ w/ PS-GTRs... this fellow on Xilinx's forum brings up an excellent point (https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Serial-Transceivers/USB-3-0-superspeed-differential-impedance/td-p/885809) on how much tolerance is required to support cheap cables. Since your SoM vendor has committed those XCVRs to 100 ohms, I think your best bet may be maintaining the 100ohms all the way to the USB port / implementation and doing an excellent job of length-matching within the pairs.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I had seen this post and was still unsure about why 90 was chosen over 100... trial and error I suppose. Still curious about coupling caps displacement currents in relation to diff pair impedance.

Answer (score 1):

My first cut would be just route your stuff 90 ohms and accept some reflection at the sharp transition.  It won't be much, even worst case.

My second cut would be to transition from 100 ohms to 90 ohms with some tapered traces.  There will be reflections still, but there will be less of a chance that there'll be one magic frequency where things go rotten.